# How to check if an item in a table is between two times M:N

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a many to many relationship between two entities. Computer and Booking, with the link entity being BookingToComputer which contains bookingID and computerID. Im trying to check that the computer is available for booking before adding it to the tables.

So I've selected the date, time, and hours of use (3 attributes in the booking table) of existing Booking records. I've created two time variable, start time (totalTime) and the end time of a booking (endtime). I've tried to put a loop to where each item in my list would go through all the selected rows from a datagridview to check if they match but I don't think I got it quite right and at this point im super confused.

```
    Dim Part1 As String = txtTime.Text + ":00:00"
    Dim Part2 As String = "00:" + txtTime1.Text + ":00"
    Dim Part3 As String = "00:00:" + txtTime2.Text

    Dim Time1 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(Part1)
    Dim Time2 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(Part2)
    Dim Time3 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(Part3)

    Dim TotalTime As TimeSpan = Time1 + Time2 + Time3

    SQL.AddParam("@Time", txtTime.Text & ":" & txtTime1.Text & ":" & txtTime2.Text)
    SQL.AddParam("@Date", txtDate.Text)
    SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT bc.Computer_ID, hours_of_use, time_of_use FROM BookingToComputer AS bc, Computer AS c, Booking AS b 
                   WHERE bc.Booking_ID = b.Booking_ID AND c.Computer_ID = bc.Computer_ID AND b.date_of_use = @Date AND b.time_of_use <= @Time;")

    DataGridView2.DataSource = SQL.DBDT
    If DataGridView2.Rows.Count() > 0 Then

         'cell1 contains the hours used and time contains the time'
        Dim TimeInt As Integer = DataGridView2.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value
        Dim TimeInt2 As TimeSpan = DataGridView2.Rows(0).Cells(2).Value

        Dim Addit As String = TimeInt.ToString + ":00:00"

        Dim interv As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(Addit)
        Dim endtime As TimeSpan = TimeInt2 + interv
        Dim rowpass As Integer = 0

        For Each x In listpick
            Dim CompID As Integer = DataGridView2.Rows(rowpass).Cells(0).Value

            If x = CompID Then

                If endtime > TotalTime Then

                    MsgBox(x & " is already reserved.")

                Else
                    MsgBox("diff time, same comp")
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox("Good time - diff comp")
            End If
            rowpass = rowpass + 1
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: I struggle with how you fill your SQL.DBDT to use as datasource for your grid. i would have exspected some like             DBDT = New DataTable
            DBDA = New SqlDataAdapter(DBcmd)
            RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)

Comment: I have an SQL control imported into a class so all I have to do is call the class which Ive declared as SQL

Comment: What is the datatype of date_of_use and time_of_use in the database? What is the database? You are sending strings so a comparison of less than or greater than is vague.